# Does a sole natural weapon attack count as two handed when using power attack?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat, feats

Does a sole natural weapon attack count as two handed when using power attack for the purpose of determining damage? For the dnd 3.5 system?

Power attack states:

> On your action, before making attack rolls for a round, you may choose to subtract a number from all melee attack rolls and add the same number to all melee damage rolls. This number may not exceed your base attack bonus. The penalty on attacks and bonus on damage apply until your next turn.
>   If you attack with a two-handed weapon, or with a one-handed weapon wielded in two hands, instead add twice the number subtracted from your attack rolls. You can’t add the bonus from Power Attack to the damage dealt with a light weapon (except with unarmed strikes or natural weapon attacks), even though the penalty on attack rolls still applies.

Natural attack states:

> A creature’s primary natural weapon is its most effective natural attack, usually by virtue of the creature’s physiology, training, or innate talent with the weapon. An attack with a primary natural weapon uses the creature’s full attack bonus, and its damage includes its full Strength modifier (1-1/2 times its Strength bonus if the attack is with the creature’s sole natural weapon).

Does this mean that for the purposes of power attack a creature with only one natural attack would count this attack as being “two handed” for the purposes of applying 2X the amount subtracted from the attack roll to the damage?

Comment: Is this different from [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/87551/8610)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a creature with one natural attack and no weapons benefit from feats that require the use of two-handed weapons?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/87551/can-a-creature-with-one-natural-attack-and-no-weapons-benefit-from-feats-that-re)

Comment: @HeyICanChan This is for dnd 3.5 the question you posted was for pathfinder. I know they are similar systems in many ways but I am looking for 2.5 ruling specifically :)

Comment: @Khaldhool That's cool. Carry on then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is common enough to houserule them to do so, to mirror the 1½ Str bonus they receive to damage, but the official rules do not specify this anywhere, so as written natural attacks do not get the 2:1 damage bonus that two-handers do. They receive only the usual 1:1 bonus, and that only because they are excepted from the clause that specifies that light weapons receive no bonus.